# Why Standard numbers of availability zones per region is 3?

Tags: cloud, high-availability

As per the documentation of AWS, Azure, and GCP cloud offerings, in most cases, the standard number of availability zones per region is 3. When we talk about High availability (HA), we can also achieve it when we have 2 availability zones such as one fails, another is a fallback.